# How to call stored procedure that returns 1 row?

Tags: c#, database, stored-procedures, oracle11g

How to call a procedure in C# to return 1 row only?

When I run this code I wrote, I get this error:

> ORA-06502 :PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Code:

```
con.Open();

OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand();
comm.Connection = con;
comm.CommandText = "GetFirstName";
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

comm.Parameters.Add("ssnid", global.passuser);
comm.Parameters.Add("fname", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

textBox2.Text = comm.Parameters["fname"].ToString();
```

Procedure:

```
create or replace procedure  GetFirstName
(ssnid in VARCHAR2 ,  fname out VARCHAR2)
as
begin
select firstname
into fname
from passenger
where ssn = ssnid ;
end;
```

Comment: You have an oracle error.  Usually it is due to the oracle driver not working with the version of oracle that you are using.  What driver are you using in the connection string?  What version of Oracle are you using for the database?  Check the oracle database log file for more info.

Comment: By the way, you should dispose all your SQL objects with `using` blocks, do not cache the connection, create it when you need it from the connection string

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this syntax

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("ssnid",OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = global.passuser;
 // or global.passuser.ToString();
```

and by the way fix this too

```
textBox2.Text = comm.Parameters["fname"].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

**PROCEDURE**

````
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETFIRSTNAME(ssnid VARCHAR2 ,  fname OUT VARCHAR2)

AS  
BEGIN

   SELECT 
   firstname INTO  fname
   FROM (SELECT 1 as ssn,'IM TOM CHANNEL' as firstname FROM dual)
   WHERE ssn = ssnid;

END GETFIRSTNAME;
```SQL

C# code is :

```C#
public void GETFIRSTNAME(string ssnid)
        {

            try
            {
                string vfname = "";
                ConnDB();
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = "GETFIRSTNAME";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("ssnid", OracleType.VarChar).Value = ssnid;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("fname", OracleType.VarChar,200).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                vfname = cmd.Parameters["fname"].Value.ToString();
               
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Dispose();
                con.Close();
            }


        }
````